Using asp-validation-for in foreach, doesn't recognize fields and gives error
I'm using Razor pages for my ASP.NET project. After cloning the repository, it started giving one specific build error :
Error (active)
CS1061  List< CaseFileStatus > does not contain a definition for 'CreatedTime_' and no accessible extension method 'CreatedTime_' accepting a first argument of type 'List< CaseFileStatus >' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Here is the codeblock which gives the error :
@model List<CaseFileStatus>

@if (Model.Any())
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    ....
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input name="CreatedTime" id="CreatedTime_@item.ID" class="form-control" value="@item.CreatedTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm")" />
        <span asp-validation-for="CreatedTime_@item.ID" class="text-danger"></span> <---- this is the line with the error
    </div>
    ....

And here is the model :
public class CaseFileStatus {
        ....
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int CaseFileID { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
        .....

Developer of the project told and show me that he is not having any issues with that usage so I'm beginning to think I have the problem in my project or machine and it started to drive me crazy.
Clean+rebuilding, restarting project or my computer didn't solve my problem.

Perhaps sit together with the developer and debug together (peer programming) as he said no issue on his side.

AFAIK, asp-* tag helper is for ASP.NET Core or .NET 5 and above, not ASP.NET (.NET Framework). Do you install the correct .NET Core Runtime/SDK? Check your project's Target Framework and install the runtime through the .NET website or via Visual Studio Installer.

@Yong project is using .NET 6 framework. I have my SDKs and runtime installed accordingly. asp-validation-for tag works for other expressions, not for CreatedTime_@item.ID

Unfortunately, I copy your code to my local ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project and cannot reproduce your error. Maybe you try to reproduce the same error with the new project. Or can you share your repository on GitHub?

If you want to post the list model to backend with received parameter(List<CaseFileStatus> model) like below:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(List<CaseFileStatus> model)
{
    //do your stuff...
    return View(model);
}

Model Binding binds the property by name attribute. The correct name for list model should be:[index].PropertyName. asp-validation-for tag helper expects a model property name, but you're trying to dynamically create an identifier using Razor syntax, which isn't valid in this context. You need change your View like below:
@if (Model.Any()) 
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input name="[@i].CreatedTime" id="CreatedTime_@item.ID" class="form-control" value="@item.CreatedTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm")" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model[@i].CreatedTime" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        i++;
    } 
}

